# Find documents where object id $in sub array using sails.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

So I have a model that is for a recipe where it has a relation of 'ingredients' and that is just an array of ObjectIds.  When I run the following query on mongo shell it works fine and returns all my data.

```
Example model :
{
"name": "...",    
"_id": ObjectId("530ca903746515c0161e6b9f"),    
"ingredients": [
    ObjectId("53069363ff7447a81a3a7a1d"),
    ObjectId("53069363ff7447a81a3a7a17")
 ]    
}

Query:
db.drink.find({"ingredients":{"$in":[ObjectId("53069364ff7447a81a3a7a87"), ObjectId("530fb948c1a3ff480d58e43c")]}});
```

Using sails.js though their waterline orm, they don't really have a way to query this though or at least through any possible google search that I can find.  So trying to use the native driver I have something like the following -

```
var ings = new Array();
for (var i in req.body) {
  ings.push(new ObjectID(req.body[i].toString()));
}
Drink.native(function(err, collection){
  if(err){
    return res.send(err, 500);
  } else {
    collection.find({"ingredients":{"$in":ings}}).toArray(function(err, data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
});
```

The thing is the data array returned in the callback is always empty.  If I check the 'ings' array it is an array of objectids so I am not sure why it won't return any data.  If I remove the json object in the 'find' function it does return everything.  Anyone have any idea how to make this query return data when using sails.js?

Comment: Have you verified that the `ings` array you're using in the `find` query contains the correct data?

Comment: You are correct Scott, it was two things, one was for some reason the ids I had were not matching from one item to another.  If I manually hard coded in the id from my example above to the ings array it then worked. Thanks for the great catch, hope that this can help others though as I had a hard time finding an example on the web doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The code above actually is working it was an internal data issue on the mongodb where IDs were not matching between relations.  When the relations were rebuilt all is working as it should be.